# Retrieving data from HTML Code using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html

The following code is for retrieving the top tweets in the sites: 
http://favstar.fm/all-time-most-favorited-tweets

When i run the code i found nothing retrieved from the HTML Nodes but i viewed the source code and i found :

```
<p class='fs-tweet-text'>If only Bradley's arm was longer. Best photo ever. <a class="tweet-url hashtag" href="https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23oscars" title="#oscars">#oscars</a> <a href="http://t.co/C9U5NOtGap" title="http://twitter.com/TheEllenShow/status/440322224407314432/photo/1">pic.twitter.com/C9U5NOtGap</a></p>
```

Source:

```
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc;
        try
        {
            doc = web.Load("http://favstar.fm/all-time-most-favorited-tweets");

            var Tweetsnodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='fs-tweet-text]").ToList();
            if (Tweetsnodes != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    URLs.Add(Tweetsnodes[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            var Usernodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a [@class='fs-tweeter']").ToList();
            if (Usernodes != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    Titles.Add(Usernodes[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

.. Can anyone tell me why i retrieved nothing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sites requires `User-Agent` header be set. (See what your code returns `var html = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;`).

You can set it as:

```
 web.UserAgent = "Stackoverflow/1.0";
```

After fixing the little typo `//p[@class='fs-tweet-text']` in your xpath, it should work

Comment: I set it and edited the little typo and didn't work !! .. Any other soln ?